# orm sequelize запрос из двух разных таблиц при загрузки одной страницы

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: нужно отображать данные на одной страничке(page.hbs) разных таблиц. Использую nodejs, orm sequelize, БД mysql, Handlebars.
При методе get к страничке page.hbs надо получить данные из двух разных таблиц.
Вот мой код:

models:

```
var roof_type = sequelize.define('roof_type', {
id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true
    }
});

return roof_type;


var garret_type = sequelize.define('garret_type', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: true
    }

});

return garret_type;
```

authcontroller.js:

```
exports.page_admin = function (req, res) {
db.roof_type.findAll({
    description: 'description ASC'

}).then(function (data) {

    var hbsObject = {
        roof_types: data
    };
    res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
});
}


exports.page_admin = function (req, res) {
db.garret_type.findAll({
    description: 'description ASC'

}).then(function (data) {

    var hbsObject = {
        garret_types: data
    };
    res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
});
}
```

routes:

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

app.get('/page_admin', isLoggedIn, authController.page_admin);
```

.........

Просьба помочь(я не очень понимаю как в одном get запросе обратиться к двум таблицам, как я понимаю нужно подправить authcontroller.js(объединить запросы) )
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.page_admin = function (req, res) {

var hbsObject = {};
var count = 0;

db.roof_type.findAll({
  description: 'description ASC'
}).then(function (data) {
  hbsObject.roof_types = data;
  count++;
  if(count == 2)
    res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
});

db.garret_type.findAll({
  description: 'description ASC'
}).then(function (data) {
  hbsObject.garret_types = data;
  count++;
  if(count == 2)
    res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
});

}
```

Так пейсали между "дедовским" способом и стандартом 2015.

```
var async = require('async');
exports.page_admin = function (req, res) {

var hbsObject = {};
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    db.roof_type.findAll({
      description: 'description ASC'
    }).then(function (data) {
      hbsObject.roof_types = data;
      callback(hbsObject);
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    db.garret_type.findAll({
      description: 'description ASC'
    }).then(function (data) {
      hbsObject.garret_types = data;
      callback(hbsObject);
    });
  }], function(err, hbsObject) {
        if(err) console.error(err);
        res.render('page_admin', hbsObject);
      });
};
```

Кстате, в Express есть специальный объект res.locals для коллекционирования данных для динамической генерации, и если добавлять в него - `res.locals.roof_types = data;` и `res.locals.garret_types = data;` - то не нужно второго аргумента - `res.render('page_admin');`, - он уже там.

Comment: async/await используется с babel сейчас или с приставкой `--harmony` (сейчас не желательно использовать, не стабильная версия). Зачем советовать то, что пока что лучше не использовать. Как по мне Promises сейчас лучший вариант, а твой уже никуда не годится. И да, может когда-то так и делали, но сейчас так уже не делают и это не считается нормальным написанием кода, так что будь проще.

Comment: Но с приставной, которая как раз и показывает что эта версия node.js на стадии разработки. Посмотри на график LTS, пока что лучше dev версию не использовать для прод., но в скором времени, а именно в октябре выйдет LTS для 8 версии и тогда хоть залейся с async/await

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать вот так:

```
module.exports.page_admin = (req, res, next) => {
  return db.sequelize.Promise.all([
    db.roof_type.findAll({
      description: 'description ASC'
    }),
    db.garret_type.findAll({
      description: 'description ASC'
    })
  ])
  .spread((roof_types, garret_types) => {
    return res.render('page_admin', {
      roof_types,
      garret_types
    });
  })
  .catch(next);
}
```